# Reg : WorkFlow Fire After record creation

Tags: workflow

I have secnario like i have to create a workflow.That worklflow have to fire when ever record is create after 2 sec. Can any one suggest me how to write the time based work flow.

Comment: After 2 seconds -- not 1, not 3 -- ?  Explain your use case in more detail - timebased workflows can't be scheduled at such a small time displacement increment

Comment: @cropredy  1sec also ok. I have a afterupdate trigger it will update some account records based upon contact update so i am updateing contact by using  WFH.So i have to update the contact after record is create with in secns,

Answer (score 1):

Ok, normally, you would update all related SObjects in the same transaction via the afterUpdate logic.  But, if for whatever reason you can defer the update of related records to a small time interval after the trigger transaction completes you have three reasonable options

- @future methods - pass in the IDs of the records to update
- Queueable methods - pass in IDs or SObjects, or any Apex Type
- Time-based workflows using a [clever workaround with offsets from a time in the past](http://www.buanconsulting.com/time-based-workflows-that-firein-less-than-1-hour/)

I've used the time-based workflow trick before but it can't be guaranteed to run even a minute after triggering.  In fact, based on system load, none of the approaches have any guaranteed response time although most of the time, @future will run pretty damn quickly (in secs) after invocation.

Comment: i have a map which consist of id,Contact how can i pass to Queable method.